# Free energy calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, phonons, free-energy

I want to plot the relationship between free energy and temperature. I want to consider two plots, when phonons are considered and when phonons are not considered how the free energy changes with temperature. I have already performed phonon calculations on my system using vasp-dfpt. All ideas are welcom.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but please show us the calculations that you have performed (both input and output files). It's hard for us to answer without knowing what data you have.

Comment: @NikeDattani I have calculated E-V data and phonon calculations to get the frequencies. I don't think is possible to upload the files here, right?